# A Lie algebra associated to a foliation(A kind of saturation of foliations)

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, foliations

Inspired  by the  Lie algebra discussed   [in this   answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/193650/a-vector-space-associated-with-a-vector-field-on-a-symplectic-manifold/303162#303162),  we  consider the  following  Lie  agebra  associated to  a  given foliation:

Let  $\mathcal{F}$  be  a nontrivial foliation of  a  manifold  $M$  tangent to  integrable subbundle $D$  of  $TM$.  We define  the  following  Lie  algebra  of  vector  fields on $M$:

$$A_{\mathcal{F}}=\{Y\in \chi^{\infty}(M)\mid [X,Y]\;\; \text{is  tangent to $\mathcal{F}$} \text{ for  all } X\in \Gamma (D)\} $$

In  fact $A_{\mathcal{F}}$ is  the  idealizer of  the  Lie  algebra $L_{\mathcal{F}}$  of  vector  fields on $M$ which are tangent to the  foliation.

> First  Question: Is there a  foliation $\mathcal{F}$ for  which  $A_{\mathcal{F}}=L_{\mathcal{F}}$?
>
> The  second  question:Is it true  to say that the  dimension of  $\{Y(p)\mid Y \in A_{\mathcal{F}}\}\subseteq T_pM$ is  independent of  Choosing $p\in M$?

If the  answer  of the  second  question is yes, [then $A_{\mathcal{F}}$  defines an integrable   distribution](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/302578/a-non-integrable-distribution-arising-from-a-lie-algebra-of-vector-fields/302579#302579) $D'$ containing the initial  distribution $D$. It  generates  a  foliation $\mathcal{F}'$ which would be  defined  as  saturation of  $\mathcal{F}$.

> Is there an  example of  this  situation such that $dim(\mathcal{F}) <dim({\mathcal{F}')<dim(M)}$?

**Remark:** As  we see in the  linked question, when we  have  a  $1$-dimensional foliation $\mathcal{F}$ tangent to  a  non vanishing  vector  field $X$ on  a  surface  $M$ with  volume  form $\omega$  , then the  Lie  algebra $A_{\mathcal{F}}$ is  equal to $$\{Y\mid [X,Y]=fX,\;\text{for  some }f\in C^{\infty}(M)\}=\{Y\in X^{\infty}(M)\mid X.\omega(X,Y)=Div X\omega(X,Y)\}$$.

**Added:** According to the comment of Bertram Arnold we add the following question:

> Is it true to say that there is an open dense subset $U\subset M$ with the following two properties:

1) For every $x\in U,\; \{V(x)|V\in A_{\mathcal{F}}\}=T_x M \}$.

2)$U$ and $M\setminus U$ are $\mathcal{F}$- saturated.

Then it seems that $M\setminus U$ is a characyteristic set in the sence that it is invariant under every leaf preserving diffeomorphism.

Comment: Except for trivial cases $A_{\mathcal F}$ will not be (sections of a) subbundle since it is not closed under multiplication by $C^\infty(M)$. By Frobenius's theorem you can find local charts such that $D = \langle \partial_1,\dots,\partial_k\rangle$. Then $A_{\mathcal F} = \{f_i(x)\partial_i\mid \partial_i f_j = 0\text{ for }i\le k < j\}$ which is not closed under multiplication by $x_{k+1}$ unless $k = 0$ (or $k=n$, in which case this function doesn't exist).

Comment: @BertramArnold Thanks for your comment. So we do not get a new foliation. That is the second and third question has negative answer. But  what about the first auestion? I revise the question by adding a questlon in the last part of the post.

Comment: As for the added question, I don't think it's possible to have such a $U$ that is not the whole of $M$, just because all the definitions involved are sheaf theoretic, hence "local", and all foliations (regular and of the same codimension), on manifolds of the same dimension, locally look the same.

Answer (score 2):

**1. First question**

The answer to your first question is yes: consider $D=TM$. 
In other words, the foliation $\mathcal F$ has a unique leaf, which is $M$ itself. Hence $A_{\mathcal F}=L_{\mathcal F}=\mathfrak{X}(M)$.

**2. $A_{\mathcal F}$ are not sections of a bundle on $M$**

As Bertram Arnold says, $A_{\mathcal F}$ is not stable under multiplication by functions in $C^\infty(M)$. But it is stable under multiplication by functions $f$ that are constant along the leaves (functions on $M/\mathcal F$, so to say).

**3. A bit of symplectic geometry**

There is a nice symplectic interpretation of the geometric setup you describe. You can skip it and go directly to the next paragraph if you don't know anything about symplectic geometry. Consider the cotangent space $T^*M$, which is a symplectic manifold. Functions on this are generated by functions on $M$ and vector fields, and the corresponding Poisson bracket is defined by: 
$$
\{X,f\}=X\cdot f\quad\mathrm{and} \quad\{f,g\}=0\,.
$$
On can then consider the ideal $\mathcal I_D$ generated by $\Gamma(D)$. Geometrically this is the ideal of functions vanishing on the zero locus of the induced dual map 
$$
T^*M\longrightarrow D^*
$$
This zero locus is a coisotropic submanifold, and thus one can perform symplectic reduction. Algebraically (i.e. on the level of functions), it amounts to consider the quotient $NP(\mathcal I_D)/\mathcal I_D$ of the Poisson normalizer $NP(\mathcal I_D)$ of the ideal by the ideal itself. 
Reduced spaces are in general quite singular. But, morally speaking, the reduced space shall be thought of as $T^*(M/\mathcal F)$, the cotangent to the leaf space $M/\mathcal F$.

**4. What is $A_{\mathcal F}/L_{\mathcal F}$ ?**

One can see from **2** and **3** above that $A_{\mathcal F}/L_{\mathcal F}$ is the Lie algebra of vector fields on $M/\mathcal F$. If the leaf space happens to be a manifold, then $A_{\mathcal F}/L_{\mathcal F}$ will be the space of sections of a vector bundle on $M/\mathcal F$ (the tangent bundle of $M/\mathcal F$), and thus so will be $A_{\mathcal F}$. Hence, in this case, the answer to your second question will be yes.

**5. Last question**

I would guess the answer to your last question is no. This is because having $\{V(x)|V\in A_{\mathcal F}\}=T_xM$ for every $x\in U$ means that $D_{|U}=TM_{|U}$. Indeed,  if $V\in L_{\mathcal F}$ is non-zero at $x$, then we chose a function $f$ such that $(V\cdot f)(x)=1$ and we have 
$$
V'(x)=[V,fV'](x)-f(x)[V,V'](x)\in D_x
$$
for every vector field $V'$. Hence $D_{|U}=TM_{|U}$.

Thus, if $U$ is moreover dense ($U$ being non-empty and $M$ connected is actually sufficient), then you get that $D=TM$.

Comment: "Consider the cotangent space $T^{*}M$, which is a symplectic manifold. Functions on this are generated by functions on $M$ and vector fields" - I think the precise statement would be: functions *polynomial along the fibers of* $T^{*}M\to M$ are generated (as an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra) by functions on $M$ and vector fields.

Comment: @DamienC  Thank  you for  your answer. i  try to  understand its  details.

Comment: I  can  Not  follow  the  first  line! Are  you  considering  the  trivial  foliation of  $M$,  as  you  wrote  $D=TM$? Or  you  are  considering  a  foliation of the  (co) tangent  bundle? In your  answer  what  is  a  precise  foliation $\mathcal{F}$ for  which $A_{\mathcal{F}}=L_{\mathcal{F}}$?

Comment: Are you  considering  a  special  connection on $M$  which  is  integrable  as a  distribution on $TM$ ? Could you please  clarify  your  answer?

Comment: The first line of my answer is not related to the rest of the answer. In the first line, yes, I consider the trivial foliation on $M$.

Comment: @AliTaghavi: I don't understand your question. There are no connections in this business. Here "distribution" means 'subbundle".

Comment: So in the first questiob i certainly do not consider the trivial foliation since in this case the question is trivial. I consider a foliation with proper dimension. In that full dimension I do not see how is your computation necessary since the matter is obvious.

Comment: Certainly by this question I was considering non trivial foliation. I revise the question. Could you please revise your answer on the first part of the question?thank you.